# Issue with C# browse button

Tags: c#, winforms

I am building an application that needs to browse for an excel file and load it.

The issue I'm facing so far is this:

When debugging the application automatically opens the browse for file dialog without having me to click the browse button.

```
namespace MassyDataMigration
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();            
        }

        private void btnLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LoadNewFile();
        }

        private void LoadNewFile()
        {
            OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
            ofd.Title = "Open required excel file";
            ofd.Filter = "EXCEL 97-03 Files|*.xls|EXCEL Files|*.xlsx";
            ofd.InitialDirectory = @"C:\";            
            System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult dr = ofd.ShowDialog();
            if (dr == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                UserSelectedFilePath = ofd.FileName;
            }
        }

        public string UserSelectedFilePath
        {
            get
            {
                return tbFilePath.Text;
            }
            set
            {
                tbFilePath.Text = value;
            }
        }

        private void tbFilePath_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Probably you've called `LoadNewFile` method somewhere else `btnLoad_Click`!

Comment: The release version works, i just get the browse window before the actual forms where I click the browse button and then get the dialog box

Comment: Seem wiring issue. Check whether event is attached to the button click event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for top one this time now i debug to confirmly check the solution:
it is working fine and showing browse dialog on debugging put his code:

```
OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
DialogResult dr = ofd.ShowDialog();
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I was looking for:

```
private void browsebtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog of = new OpenFileDialog();
    of.Filter = "Excel Files|*.xls;*.xlsx";
    if (of.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        textBoxBrowse.Text = of.FileName;
    }
}   

private void textBoxBrowse_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

This is the code I added and it works. Thank you html.inn for your answer! Great stuff!

Answer (score 0):

The work is too simple you are making it too complicated to show a browse dialog box code is such like that:

```
DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
```

Now you can use this where ever you want it to automatically show like you want to show it on page load you can work with it inside form1()
constructor or where ever you want it to show.

Comment: Not sure this answer addresses his "When debugging the application automatically opens the browse for file dialog without having me to click the browse button" issue